# 403 Forbidden error when using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, http-status-code-403

I am getting this error while trying the Youtube API

[image]

Why does it say so?

Answer (score 0):

Please, replace your `token` into `[YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]` in the `curl`

Comment: doesn't that thing gets added automatically when I click authorise

Comment: Yeah, i think, you need to get `token` from your console
This is document from youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization